# Offset on value null issue for Mailtrap on Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, mailtrap

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4.

I'm using Mailtrap for test emails. I just upgraded my Laravel version to 7.4 and my email has been stopped to work. When I try to send demo email, it gives me an error below

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

The issue is here:

```
 {{ $mailData['title'] }}
```

Controller:

```
class MailController extends Controller {

    public function sendEmail() {
        $email = 'positronx@gmail.com';

        $mailData = [
            'title' => 'Demo Email',
            'url' => 'https://www.positronx.io'
        ];

        Mail::to($email)->send(new EmailDemo($mailData));

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Email has been sent.'
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

MailFile:

```
class EmailDemo extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $mailData;

    public function __construct()
    { }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('email.demoEmail')
            ->with('mailData', $this->mailData);
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
@component('mail::message')
     {{ $mailData['title'] }}

    The body of your message.

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => $mailData['url']])
        Button Text
    @endcomponent

    Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to set $mailData in the `constructor()`, pass it to the constructor and set it to `$this->maildata`.

```
class EmailDemo extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $mailData;

    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops my goodness !
How can I skip the very main part.. 
Working now !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

you have not initialized the `$mailData` in the mail notification class. you can do it as below:

```
class EmailDemo extends Mailable
{
    //your other code
    public $mailData;

    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }
}
```

it will work now hopefully.

Comment: #mrhn has already suggested me the same solution above. Still I appreciate your response !